# Installing android apk app from web

Tags: android, web, installation, apk

I'd like to publish my own Android application as an .apk file on a web-page.

I link to the file using an ordinary a href.

I've created an .htaccess file with the line:

```
AddType application/vnd.android.package-archive apk
```

And the mime-type seems to work. Chrome (on a PC) reports the type as expected.

BUT when i click the link from my Nexus 7 (Android 4.2) it opens a dialog saying "Complete action using?"

Here I can select "Chrome" - which results in an identical dialog.

I tried to install Dolphin browser, and it offes to save the file - afterwards it can be installed by clicking the downloaded file. But I rather not force people to download another program to be able to install mine.

Comment: use dropbox, get a public link from there, convenient free hosting. although I heard they were removing that in some future time for new users

Comment: As a workaround, Chrome users have the option to long-press on the link and choose "Save link".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough?!

Chrome stopped asking questions and now it happily downloads the file each time I click it. Don't know what happend. Thanks for the replys.